# How can I create a function with categorical input in R?

Tags: r

In order to analyse the association between the output variable (qualitative) and several predictors (qualitative) each at a time, I'd rather write a function, but it doesn't work.

I've followed these steps:

```
# take the variable names (predictors)
# from the dataset Data in a character vector 
qualitative_predictors <- c("Data$col2", "Data$col5", "Data$col9")

association <- function(x) {
  cont_table <- table(Data$output, x)  # create a contingency table of the two categorical variable
  Phi(cont_table)                      # DescTools package   
  } # create a function for each combinations of variable output
# (in this case Data$output) and each predictor which I want to analyse # association with. I've picked Phi index from the DescTools package 
# (it could have been Cramer's V: I guess it doesn't matter at this
# stage). 

association(qualitative_predictors) # I call the function using the vector I've created.
```

I receive this error message:

> Error in table(Data$Flag_Richiesta_Estinzione_cc, x) :
> tutti gli argomenti devono avere la medesima lunghezza

Translation:

> all elements must have the same length

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem and help you better.

Comment: Don't pass the names of the columns you want to test.  Pass the columns themselves.

Comment: I've passed the colums. It works! Thank you @Limey